# PlaceAutoCompleteFragment setHint NPE

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NPE on the `setHint` method.
Logcat shows this error:

```
void android.widget.EditText.setHint(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.
```

Here is my code:

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_NONE)
            .build();
    if (pickup_point == null) {
        Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "autocompleteFragment_null");
        pickup_point = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) PlaceAutocompleteFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), "com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment");
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pickup_container, pickup_point).commit();
                 Fn.logD("pickup_point_fragment",String.valueOf(pickup_point));
        pickup_point.setFilter(typeFilter);
        if ((southwest != null)) {
            Fn.SystemPrintLn("******haha**my curn loc is : " + southwest.longitude + " " + southwest.latitude);
            pickup_point.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast));
        }
        pickup_point.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "onPlaceSelected");
                pickuppoint_name = (String) place.getName();
                pickup_address = (String) place.getAddress();
                pickup_latlng = place.getLatLng();
                pickup_lat = pickup_latlng.latitude;
                pickup_lng = pickup_latlng.longitude;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "onError");
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
        pickup_point.setHint("Pickup Point");
    }
    if (dropoff_point == null) {
        Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "autocompleteFragment_null");
        dropoff_point = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) PlaceAutocompleteFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), "com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment");
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dropoff_container, dropoff_point).commit();
        //pickup_point.setHint("Pickup Point");
        dropoff_point.setFilter(typeFilter);
        if ((southwest != null)) {
            dropoff_point.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast));
        }
        dropoff_point.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                Fn.logD("BOOKNOW_FRAGMENT", "onPlaceSelected");
                dropoffpoint_name = (String) place.getName();
                dropoff_address = (String) place.getAddress();
            }
```

This is the relevant code from the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
        style="@style/horizontal_LL.sm.2">
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/edittext_fragment"
            android:id="@+id/pickup_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/horizontal_LL.sm.2">
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/edittext_fragment"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/dropoff_container">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I know pretty much about NPE and how to solve them, but I could not find a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

This seems to be the issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23972

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `setHint()` method try to execute the pending transactions after you've inserted the PlaceAutocompleteFragment by calling :

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
```